# JPA relationship with extra predicate

Tags: jpa

I need to map a 1:N relationship (on database) as a 1:1 (on java classes).

Let me explain: suppose 2 entities, Person and Address.

A Person may have many Addresses (the 1:N part), but only one of these Addresses is current‡ (by some criteria, maybe a boolean flag indicating its currency or a couple of date fields "not before" and "not after").

In SQL, I want something like:

```
SELECT p.*, a.* FROM Person p LEFT JOIN Address a ON (p.id = a.person_id AND a.is_valid = TRUE)
```

There is a restriction that none or at most one Address will be valid. This is enforced elsewhere.

**How to declare the relationship Person->Address?**

I get that the join criteria is the `p.id = a.person_id` part above. But I need to add extra predicate (`a.is_valid = TRUE` in the example above).

Moreover this predicate MUST BE coupled with the join clause (and not a filter to be applied after fetch), since there is the case of the persons which currently have no valid address (though may had many in the past).

```java
@Entity class Address { /* ... */}

@Entity class Person {
  /* @WhatToPutHere? */
  private Address currentAddress;
}
```

‡ Think of a badly done audit track of previous addresses.

Comment: You could probably use a `@Formula` column (or `JoinColumnOrFormula`) that fetches the current address. Or even simple a  `@Where(clause = "current is true")`.

Comment: Are these annotations standard JPA? I guess they are hibernate specific.

Comment: Indeed these are hibernate annotations

Answer (score 0):

You can have both in your entity. The current address and the list of all addresses.

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    /* anyother properties */

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_address_id")
    private Address currentAddress;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person")
    private Set<Address> addresses;

}
```

And you should only assign a valid address to currentAddress.

Comment: `current_address_id` does not exist (and cannot exist). The notion of what the current address is stems from the fact that inside the `Set<>` of all `addresses` only one of them has some property (in my example `is_valid` is true).

Comment: I could stick with just `Set<Address> addresses` and add an extra method `getCurrentAddress() { return this.addresses.stream().filter(Address::isValid).findFirst().else(null); }`. But this involves fetching all addresses. I was thinking of some shortcut to fetch just the single one that is valid. After all, SQL allows this (the `LEFT JOIN` with extra predicate beyond joining columns).

Comment: If you cannot change your database for adding a new column to fetch it in a easy way and fast way. One option is to add a getAddress as you mentioned, or you can let this property transient and then map it in you query.